# Why would vsftpd be logging to syslog even though logging is disabled in vsftpd?

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd, syslog

I have all logging disabled in /etc/vsftpd but for some reason it is still logging to /var/log/syslog and I can't figure out why.

```
root@unraid:/etc# cat /etc/vsftpd.conf 
# vsftpd.conf for unRAID
# with suggestions from forum user 'nars'
#
connect_from_port_20=NO
write_enable=YES
local_root=/mnt
local_umask=0
#
# No anonymous logins
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Allow only local vsftpd.user_list users to log in.
local_enable=YES
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_file=/boot/config/vsftpd.user_list
check_shell=NO
#
# Logging to syslog
syslog_enable=NO
log_ftp_protocol=NO
xferlog_enable=NO
#
# Misc.
dirmessage_enable=NO
ls_recurse_enable=YES
listen=NO
seccomp_sandbox=NO

chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
user_config_dir=/boot/config/vsftpd.user_config_dir
pasv_min_port=10090
pasv_max_port=10100
```

excerpt from `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Apr  5 21:03:14 unraid vsftpd[4248]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:03:24 unraid vsftpd[4285]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:03:34 unraid vsftpd[4342]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:03:45 unraid vsftpd[4475]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:03:55 unraid vsftpd[4521]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:04:05 unraid vsftpd[4613]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:04:16 unraid vsftpd[4653]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:04:26 unraid vsftpd[4691]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:04:36 unraid vsftpd[4747]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:04:47 unraid vsftpd[4782]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:04:57 unraid vsftpd[5111]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:05:08 unraid vsftpd[5201]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:05:18 unraid vsftpd[5244]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:05:28 unraid vsftpd[5297]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:05:39 unraid vsftpd[5358]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:05:49 unraid vsftpd[5400]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:05:59 unraid vsftpd[5441]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:06:10 unraid vsftpd[5526]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:06:20 unraid vsftpd[5569]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:06:30 unraid vsftpd[5610]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:06:41 unraid vsftpd[5667]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:06:51 unraid vsftpd[5709]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:07:01 unraid vsftpd[5776]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
Apr  5 21:07:12 unraid vsftpd[5853]: connect from 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)
```

Comment: rsyslog is writing to `/var/log/syslog`, you can find the configuration in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`. There is also journald - which doesn't log to `/var/log/syslog`, but nonetheless creates logs. Also.. why disable all logging? *logging is great!*

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure those lines aren't being logged by vsftpd itself, but by some other process that's monitoring network connections. The lines are written by that other process (and are saying that there was a network connection from that IP to another particular process, in this case vsftpd).